# Win + ~ Causes screen to switch between grayscale and colour

Tags: windows-10, display, display-settings

Currently the windows key and ~ (which I use in another application) switches the computer between grayscale and colour. This is a HP Elite tablet running windows 10 64 bit.

I have had a look in accessibility and searched online to disable this, so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You didn't specify the model, so I can't look up what specific software your graphics driver has and see whether it has such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Googling for any HP-specific hotkeys came up empty - nothing like this is present in the [HP docs on keyboard shortcuts](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02951398).

Most probably, this is your graphics driver software - they tend to include fancy-yet-largely-useless gimmicks like this. Usually, it has an icon in system tray area, by right-clicking which you can enter its configuration utility. Among its options, there must be something about filters and/or hotkeys.